# Convenient way of defining a list as observation in a data.frame

Tags: r, list

Is there a way of defining a list-as-observation inside the loop? For instance, I could just run the following code to replace each list-as-observation whenever another observation of a data.frame meets a certain condition, like in the code below, but I need to create the `lists` as a set of `NULL` `lists` before running the loop. Also, I haven't figured out how to place the `list` in the line that creates the `data.frame` -- is there way to do this?

Here it is the code:

```
#line that creates the data.frame: I wished to know how to place the list 
#(at the line after creating the data.frame object) inside the data.frame function.

df = data.frame(x=1:10)

#line that creates the list as NULL values before replacing them in the loop

df$y = list(c())

#random replacement condition 

df$z = c(0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0)

#Loop: could I create the list variable on the run without creating it before the loop?

for(i in 1:10) {

  if (df$z[i]==1) {

  df$y[i] = list(c("a","b"))  


  }

}
```

If there is a more state of the art or a recommend way of doing this following some set of principles (e.g. tidy) I would be glad if someone could refer to it.

Comment: Why do you want to store a _list_ in a single entry in a data frame?  This seems to be a break from normalization and best practices.

Comment: I agree with Tim, you probably don't want to add a list to a variable in each row. Maybe if you can share the problem you're trying to solve by doing this, we can help you find a better solution

Comment: I was not sure if this was the best practice, but, say, if I were running a loop in a set of folders and obtaining for each file the full name (e.g. `list(..., full.names=T)`) inside the folders. Is it really a poor practice to store each name in a list with the 'ID' being the folder?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you want to do this but you can reduce your code to

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, z = c(0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0))
df$y <- ifelse(df$z == 1, list(c("a","b")), list())
```

and it would give the same result.

Comment: Thank you, but my question lies more within the realm of the behavior of lists with data.frames. I've mentioned an example in question above: suppose I was running the loop on a set of folders and each folder has a set of files. Suppose I am creating a data.frame with the name of each folder and the name of each file. Would it be poor practice to store the name of the files in a list, by each folder?

Comment: @JohnDoe Instead of storing it in a list I would suggest storing it in separate rows for each file which would be easier to process later.